# How to use a parameter in a nested step definition?

Tags: c#, specflow

I know how to place a steps within a step definition link so:

```
[Binding]
public class PaymentPrerequisiteDefinitions : Steps
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;

    public PaymentPrerequisiteDefinitions(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
    }

    [Given(@"the prerequisite steps before the payment page are successful for a holiday over 70 days)")]
    public void GivenThePrerequisiteStepsBeforeThePaymentPageAreSuccessfulForAHolidayOverDays()
    {
        Given(@"I have a valid holiday to (*.)");
    }
```

But my question is how am I suppose to deal with the parameter? The actual step definition is here which I am reflecting from:

```
    [Given(@"I have a valid holiday to (.*)")]
    public void GivenINeedToReadInFlightData(string holidayFilter)
    {
        string selectedHoliday = _dataSource.GetFlightData(holidayFilter);

    }
```

I get a object reference error when it hits the:

```
string selectedHoliday = _dataSource.GetFlightData(holidayFilter);
```

If in my nested given statement (first block of code posted in this question) I changed the line to:

```
Given(@"I have a valid holiday to Marjorca");
```

Then it works fine but I want to be able to use the parameter like the actual given statement to allow dynamic destination.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

you have three choices.

1. Hard code like you have
2. Pass the parameter into the function which wraps your steps (I'm assuming that you have multiple nested steps, otherwise this seems pointless)
3. Set the value from a different step, save the value, and then insert it here

We tend to do #2 (as usually the steps are wrapping up many intervening steps to make the tests more readable), but occasionally we do #3, usually using [context injection](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Context-Injection) to share the value between the steps.

Comment: Thank you very much, i'll have a look and comment if I require additional assistance. Actually sam, can you show me how you implement option two using the example above please?